# WaitForSeconds error

Tags: unity, c#

I'm new to c# and coding, sorry if I sound like a noob... I don't know how to fix the waitforseconds error, and I don't know what's wrong.

```
public float restartDelay = 2f;

public TextMesh failText;
public TextMesh failTextGame;

private void Start()
{
    failTextGame.text = "";
}

System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool> OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)

{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))

    {

        failText.text = "Game Over!";
        failTextGame.text = "Try Again";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(restartDelay);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. You mentioned an error in your question; please include the actual error message text/info as it makes it far easier for others to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `WaitForSeconds` inside of the `OnTriggerEnter` function **is perfectly fine** since this function can be handled as a coroutine by Unity. Having an additional function is not needed.

The only problem with your code is the **return type of the function**

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)    
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))    
    {    
        failText.text = "Game Over!";
        failTextGame.text = "Try Again";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(restartDelay);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the documentation and it indicated that OnCollisionEnter could be a coroutine but made no such indication for OnTriggerEnter. Although I did not test it to be sure. Are you certain that OnTriggerEnter can be a coroutine?

Comment: 100% certain, I've checked it in an empty project, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Sean’s answer is correct. However, since all you are doing is waiting before calling a method, you could just use `Invoke` instead:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {

        failText.text = "Game Over!";
        failTextGame.text = "Try Again";
        Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        //Alternatively, if you are using a version of C# that supports nameof:
        //Invoke(nameof(Restart), restartDelay);
    }
}

private void Restart()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

Comment: it says that 'Restart': member names cannot be the same as their coding types...I'm not sure what this means

Comment: Is this class named Restart?